# PHP count the days until a specified day PLUS add days until a specified day of the week

Tags: php, math

I have a question regarding the PHP count function. Heres what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a field called ' Departure Date' and another called "Payment Due In'. I want to count the day from todays date, until the departure date, and record this in 'Payment Due In'.

This is simple. However, I also the condition that payments are made on a Wednesday.

This means if the departure date was on a Sunday, the sum would be:
Count today() -> time until departure date + days until Wednesday = number of days until payment is due.

Please help me out if you can!

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

here is my code block:

```
<?php 
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($search_res)){  //shows result of qry

$datetimeFromMysql = $row4['arrival_date'];
$newTime = strtotime($datetimeFromMysql);
$myFormatForView = date("d/m/Y", $newTime);

$datetimeFromMysql2 = $row4['departure_date'];
$newTime2 = strtotime($datetimeFromMysql2);
$myFormatForView2 = date("d/m/Y", $newTime2);
```

// displays this arrival / departure date in english date format

```
$DepartureDate = $row4['departure_date'];
$today = new DateTime();
$depd = new DateTime($DepartureDate);

$interval = $today->diff($depd);
$days = (int)$interval->format('%a');


// adjust to make payment due on a Wednesday
$dow = (int)$depd->format('N');
$days += ($dayOF - $dow) %7;
?>
```

// $dayOF allows user to change when they usually makes payments Mond (1) - Sun /(7)

```
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row4['reference_no'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myFormatForView?></td>
        <td><?php echo $myFormatForView2?></td>
        <?php
            echo "<form method='post' action='hostPayments.php?id=" . $row4['group_id'] ."'>" 
        ?>
        <?php if ($days == '0'){ $class="bg-warning"; } else if($depd >= $today){ $class="bg-success"; } else{ $class="bg-danger"; } ?>

        <td class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><b><?php if($days == '0'){?> TODAY! <?php } else {  echo $days; ?></b> Days <?php if($depd >= $today){ ?> Time <?php } else { ?> Ago <?php }} ?></td>     
        <td><?php echo $row4['status']; ?></td>
        <td class="danger"><button type="submit" name="host_payment" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> <b> - NOT COMPLETE</b> <span style="color: white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span></form></td>


    </tr>
<?php
}
```

if the payment is due in the future, the field is green (bg-success) and $days is outputted + the word 'Time' to read something like (7 days time)

if payment is late, the field is red (bg-danger) and $days is outputted + the word 'Ago' to read (3 days ago)

if payment is due today the field is yellow (bg-warning) and 'TODAY' is displayed

- On an entry with departure date is 9th May, the output is '6 days time' (i have changed payment usually made now to Tuesday). The system is counting to the next tuesday before the departure date, not the following Tuesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. First it figures out the payment due date based on the Departure Date and the day of the week that payments are due. Then it computes the number of days until the payment is due (or how much it is overdue). Note I have included some debugging prints which you will probably want to remove.

```
function payment_due_date($DepartureDate, $dayOf) {
    $depd = new DateTime($DepartureDate);
    // adjust to make payment due on the specified day of the week
    // 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday,...,7=Sunday
    $dow = (int)$depd->format('N');
    $depd->add(new DateInterval('P' . ((7 + $dayOf - $dow) % 7) . 'D'));
    echo 'Payment due date is: ' . $depd->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
    return $depd;
}

function payment_due_days($DepartureDate, $dayOf) {
    // get payment due date
    $depd = payment_due_date($DepartureDate, $dayOf);
    $today = new DateTime();
    // need to set time to 0 to match $DepartureDate
    $today->setTime(0,0);
    $interval = $today->diff($depd);
    $days = (int)$interval->format('%r%a');
    if ($days == 0)
        echo "Payment is due today\n";
    else if ($days > 0)
        echo "Payment is due in $days days\n";
    else
        echo "Payment was due " . abs($days) . " days ago\n";
    return $days;
}

payment_due_days('2018-05-01', 2);
payment_due_days('2018-05-01', 4);
payment_due_days('2018-05-09', 2);
payment_due_days('2018-04-20', 2);
payment_due_days('2018-05-18', 3);
payment_due_days('2018-06-02', 4);
```

Output (based on today='2018-04-30'):

```
Payment due date is: 2018-05-01
Payment is due in 1 days
Payment due date is: 2018-05-03
Payment is due in 3 days
Payment due date is: 2018-05-15
Payment is due in 14 days
Payment due date is: 2018-04-24
Payment was due 6 days ago
Payment due date is: 2018-05-23
Payment is due in 23 days
Payment due date is: 2018-06-07
Payment is due in 38 days
```

Note the reason we use `(7 + $dayOf - $dow) % 7` is that PHP returns negative numbers from `%` if the value is negative. Otherwise we would use `($dayOf - $dow) %7`. This is the reason your code gives the wrong due date for a departure date of May 9th.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This isn't working when todays date is similar to the departure date

Comment: Hi blackers, what do you mean exactly? I've tried this code with `$DepartureDate` the same as `$today` and it works fine e.g. if both dates are '2018-05-01' it gives 1 day to pay (which is correct since today is Tuesday and tomorrow is Wednesday). Can you give me an example of when it didn't work?

Comment: Hi Nick, I've edited above. Hope it's clear and thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: See my edit. I think it meets your new requirements.

Comment: This seems to be working now! Didn't work within the function but just kept changing things round, someone works but I have no idea haha, thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Glad you managed to make it work! Sometimes integrating someone else's code is harder than writing it yourself.